# Hyperledger Fabric Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've found that in  Hyperledger composer playground anyone can delete the current business network. How can I restrict it so that only an admin can delete their own business network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between hyperledger composer and hyperledger fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505333/difference-between-hyperledger-composer-and-hyperledger-fabric)

Comment: Yes I know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric Composer is an old and temporary name and has been replaced with [Hyperledger Composer](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/composer).  It is the same thing